# Java 8 - java 11 migration issues

Tags: java, java-8, migration, java-11

We are migration one of our applications from java 8 to java 11.

I made changes in build.gradle

```
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
```

And added

```
compile("com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.2")
```

Also made changes to vela file for docker image

Seeing the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class java/lang/UnknownError could not be instrumented.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:140)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:101)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.PreMain.createRuntime(PreMain.java:55)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:47)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1999)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:138)
    ... 9 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at ./src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
```

No other changes are done. Am i supposed to change anything in test cases or add any dependencies? Any suggestion related to this would be helpful.

Comment: This seems to be a problem of jacoco and nothing else. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Actually we aren't using jacoco in our old version of the application which is running with java8. But this issue is resolved after I have updated the gradle connector version from 4.8.1 to 5.0. Thanks for responding btw.